# Issue running msiexec as Administrator in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, uac, windows-installer

I recently bought a new HP computer and I am unable to run any MSI by double clicking it. I receive an error message:

> This installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.

My account is an administrator account and I have disabled UAC. However, if I run a command line prompt as administrator and try to install the MSI package by using the below command, the software installs correctly without any error messages:

```
msiexec /package packagename.msi
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click on it, do you have the option to 'Run as administrator'?

If so, try that.

Even though your account is an administrator account, Windows 7 will still default, in many cases, to making you a 'regular user' for system safety.

Comment: That would not be the case if he disabled UAC. It will run as the logged in user and their privileges.

Comment: Windows 7 is a pain in the butt when you are logged in as admin.  I am a domain admin, and I need to right-click and choose Run as Administrator to install MSI packages, even though Windows would recognise my privileges.

Comment: Most interesting that I do not have a run as administrator on my menu selection, however, I have it on another computer. Wonder if it is something HP specific.